# Get dropdown arrow on HTML select tag

Tags: html, css

I need to create a select box that looks like this:

[image]

My Html:

```
<select class="addSelect">
  <option>Some Value</option>
  <option>Some Value</option>
  <option>Some Value</option>
</select>
```

My Sass/CSS:

```
.addSelect {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  @include border-radius(6px, 6px, 6px, 6px);
  color: #9A9A9A;
  @include appearance(none);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

So I have something like this so far:

[image]

Pretty close I'd say! (Not the colours yet of course). So, what I'm struggling with is getting that little downward facing arrow in there. When I said 'appearance: none' I effectively got rid of that dropdown arrow.. (though in chrome it was an upward AND downward facing arrow)... Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using fontawosme icons an absolute position

```css
.select{
  width:200px;
}
select{
  
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.select:before {
    content: "\f078";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 5px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='select'>
  <select class="addSelect">
     <option>Some Value</option>
     <option>Some Value</option>
     <option>Some Value</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap. They have a ton of css ready for you to use. It is really easy to setup and use. With bootstrap you can get the arrow Up and Down in your dropdown.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns